# Unable to Add new Domain User in SDL Web8 CME

Tags: cme, web8

In CME UI administration->USer Access Management when I tried to add a new domain user it gives below error in CME Notifications flag

```
This request operation sent to net.tcp://localhost:2660/CoreService/201501/netTcp did not receive a reply within the configured timeout (00:01:00). The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout. This may be because the service is still processing the operation or because the service was unable to send a reply message. Please consider increasing the operation timeout (by casting the channel/proxy to IContextChannel and setting the OperationTimeout property) and ensure that the service is able to connect to the client.
```

**And in the windows Event logs below Error was listed:**

The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServerSessionPreambleConnectionReader+ServerFramingDuplexSessionChannel, cannot be used for communication because it has been Aborted. Component: Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService Errorcode: 0 User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE StackTrace Information Details: at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.ThrowIfDisposedOrNotOpen() at System.ServiceModel.Channels.OutputChannel.Send(Message message, TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransactionDuplexChannelGeneric`1.Send(Message message, TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DuplexChannelBinder.DuplexRequestContext.OnReply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContextBase.Reply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.Reply(MessageRpc& rpc)

> I have done the fresh installation of SDL Web8 (no upgrade). Is there
>   any configuration change in installed SDL CME expected in SDL web8 to
>   fix this issue.

Comment: Is the SDL Web Content Manager Service Host service running?

Comment: @PeterKjaer: yes the Content Manager Host service is running, for a try i restarted this service but it makes no difference.

Comment: When you say it's a fresh installation, do you mean that you've never had Tridion or SDL Web installed before? Or just that you did an uninstall first? Also, do you have any firewalls or other infrastructure software that might interfere?

Comment: @PeterKjaer- yes its first time Installation of SDL Web8 and DXA 1.6 on this new box (single machine), Content Delivery and Content Manager are on same machine. All Delivery services (discovery, deployer) working fine and able to fetch a published page from Broker DB. Have not faced any firewall issue yet in any of these mentioned items, services thus i just expect it should not be linked to firewall issue

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been fixed, In the firewall certain RPC ports are dynamic, It's by default blocked in the third-party firewall (Sophos, Incapsula, F5) once we enabled RPC port range in the firewall and then it's working fine.